# How to execute terminal commands in a js file (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, discord, discord.js

My discord bot currently has a local recording feature that creates a file every time someone speaks. When the bot disconnects from the voice call (from !stoprecording), I need to manually run `node merge.js` in my terminal to merge all those files into 1 main PCM file. From there, I need to run another FFMPEG terminal command to convert the merged PCM file into an MP3. That's fine on it's own, but is was curious if there was any way I could automate that? Is there a way to execute terminal commands in the actual code itself. So that every time !stoprecording is ran, it would merge the file and convert to mp3 using FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Node.JS native stuff to exec shell command when handling discord.js bot command

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function ls() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
}

// ls function is called in command exec function
ls();
```

Comment: How exactly would that work in my code? Sorry, I am new to coding

Comment: `exec('ls')` is the command in shell replace it with whatever you want. and put `ls()` . where you want to execute command shell

Comment: So if I need to execute `node merge.js` in a different directory how do I specify that in my ls

Comment: Just doing `node ../merge.js`